# Which materials were used in the F-100 Super Sabre construction?

Tags: f-100

I was wondering if anyone could help me with any details about the materials percentage on the F-100 Super Sabre. Considering the plane is quite popular even to this day, I'm a bit frustrated that I cannot find any info regarding this on the web.